# Multi-field terms aggregation approaches

Tags: python, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm very new to DSL and am currently struggling with trying to perform a compound SQL like "Group By" on multiple fields in my Elastic Search index. I understand from the reference document on www.elastic.co that terms aggregation does not support collecting terms from multiple fields in the same document.
Two options given to overcome this limitation are either Script or Copy_to field.
Before I ask for an opinion/solution using either Script or Copy_to I'd like to understand if I've exhausted all other options.
The current code, that runs successfully, is:

```
    query_result = {"query":{
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [{"range": {"flStDttmEst": {"gte":"2017-06-20 10:00:00","lte":"2017-06-20 11:55:00",}}},
                            ],               
                    "filter": [
                            {"terms": {"proto": ["6","17"]}},
                            {"terms": {"dstAd": ["165.130.217.", "165.130.217.","165.130.217.","165.130.217.","165.130.217." ]}}      
                              ],
                           }
                         },
                  "aggregations":{
                        "SumPKTSaggs":{
                            "date_histogram":{"field":"flStDttmEst","interval":"hour","format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},
                            "aggs":{"SumPkts":{
                                "sum":{"field":"smPkts"}}}},
                        "SumACKaggs":{
                            "date_histogram":{"field":"flStDttmEst","interval":"hour","format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},
                            "aggs":{"SumACK":{
                                "sum":{"field":"smACK"}}}}


                                 }
               }
return
```

Output of the JSON and the Python Dataframe are:

```
    {
"SumACKaggs": {
    "buckets": [
        {
            "SumACK": {
                "value": 23721.0
            },
            "doc_count": 19493,
            "key": 1497952800000,
            "key_as_string": "2017-06-20 10:00:00"
        },
        {
            "SumACK": {
                "value": 23530.0
            },
            "doc_count": 19441,
            "key": 1497956400000,
            "key_as_string": "2017-06-20 11:00:00"
        }
    ]
},
"SumPKTSaggs": {
    "buckets": [
        {
            "SumPkts": {
                "value": 1310745.0
            },
            "doc_count": 19493,
            "key": 1497952800000,
            "key_as_string": "2017-06-20 10:00:00"
        },
        {
            "SumPkts": {
                "value": 1308840.0
            },
            "doc_count": 19441,
            "key": 1497956400000,
            "key_as_string": "2017-06-20 11:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
}

        time                SumOfPkts   SumOfACKs
    0   2017-06-20 10:00:00 1310745.0   23721.0
    1   2017-06-20 11:00:00 1308840.0   23530.0
```

However, my ultimate goal is to not only use time as the "group by" aggregation but also other variables like proto and dstAd.

Please advise and thanks so much for your time !!

Steve